# How do make a loading progress when I fetching an API in login function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loading

I am stuck on certain project for showing the **loading** when I try to fetch an API for login. I use

Consider the code below:

```
login(){
  const { history } = this.props;
    PostData('api/users/login', this.state)
    .then ((result) => {
      let responseJSON = result;
      this.setState({
        loaded: true
      })
      if(this.state.loaded === true){
      if(responseJSON.success === true){
        localStorage.setItem('loginEmail', this.state.loginEmail);
        localStorage.setItem('id', responseJSON.user.id);

        history.push('/Home')    // when successfully login, it will go to Home Page

      }else if(responseJSON.success === false){
        alert("Wrong User Credential")
      }}else if(this.state.loaded === false){
        return(
         <LinearProgress />    // for loading
        )
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

and here is my contructor for this.state

```
constructor (props){
  super(props);
  this.state ={
    loginEmail: '',
    loginPassword: '',
    error: {},
    loaded: false,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
  this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
```

is this the way I use for loading in my login function is wrong? Why I cannot show the **linear progress** when the loaded is false?

**Update**
[Here is my code from codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-grass-zb5ul?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Your return component is not going anywhere in this case, you need to set a variable in the state `loading` when you trigger the call to the API set it true. When the response comes back set it false. Display the `<LinearProgress/>` in the view based on the `loading` param. If you share the whole code maybe I can help

Comment: @Sabbin Hi, thanks for your reply. Here is the codesandbox link  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-grass-zb5ul?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Remove  else if case from login function. This one.

```
else if (this.state.loaded === false) {
      return (
        <LinearProgress /> // for loading
      );
    }
```

and In render below your login input field add a ternary condition that checks state and if state is false renderes `<LinearProgress />` and when state is made true by login that will move to next page.

```
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Login"
          className="logbtn"
          onClick={this.login}
        />
{(this.state.loaded)?null: <LinearProgress />}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sandbox, there are a couple of things you need to add/change

- Rename `loaded` to `isLoading` parameter to your `state` so it will be easier to understand it's usability

```js
this.state = {
    loginEmail: "",
    loginPassword: "",
    error: {},
    redirect: false,
    isLoading: false,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

- Trigger the state change to `true` when you fire the call, there are a couple of ways to do it but the simplest is to change the `isLoading` directly in the `login` function
- Add a `finally` promise handler so after the call to change the loading state to false in either case, success or fail.

```js
login() {
  const { history } = this.props;
  this.setState({isLoading:true});
  PostData("api/users/login", this.state)
    .then(result => {
      let responseJSON = result;
        if (responseJSON.success === true) {
          localStorage.setItem("loginEmail", this.state.loginEmail);
          localStorage.setItem("id", responseJSON.user.id);

          history.push("/Home"); // when successfully login, it will go to Home Page
        } else if (responseJSON.success === false) {
          alert("Wrong User Credential");
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .finally(() => this.setState({ isLoading : false }));
}
```

- The last thing is to add your `<LinearProgress />` element in the page and set the conditional for it. In your case `isLoading` to be `true`. You can place the element anywhere inside the render by adding the following line

```js
{this.state.isLoading && <LinearProgress />}
```